# Parse XML File - Tag is Reserved Word

Tags: php, xml, parsing, keyword

I am trying to get the values of data from an XML file. I am able to get other lines fine but I can't get the data between the [asin][/asin] tags as its a reserved word in PHP. I am wondering what a workaround is?

This is my code:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($request_url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$item = $xml->Items->Item[0];

// ** this is my Problem **
$asin = htmlentities((string) $item->Asin); 
// ** this is my Problem **

$title = htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Title);
```

Here is a part of the xml file:

```
    <Item>
        <ASIN>B00TSUGXKE</ASIN>
        <ParentASIN>B010BWYDYA</ParentASIN>
```

The other elements work fine. Its just this tag "Asin" its a reserved word in php so it can't be used. Is there some other way to reference just the tag not the "asin" function in php?

Comment: add sample xml in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$asin = htmlentities((string) $item->{'ASIN'});
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @alistairshaw. It turns out that the reference was case sensitive. I had tried putting it inside brackets earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$asin = htmlentities((string) $item->{'ASIN'});
```

XML is case sensitive. I did a little more testing and this worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is letter case. In XML it's upper case `ASIN` But you request in Camel case.

Should be:

`$asin = htmlentities((string) $item->ASIN);`